# ReactJS make prop the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have:

```
export default class List extends Component {
...
render() {
        return <div>
...
<DropdownMenu text="Only show" isOpen={this.state.activeDropdown === "Only_show"} onClick={() => this.setState({ activeDropdown: "Only_show"})} inMenu={this.state.mouseInDropdown} onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ mouseInDropdown: true })} onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ mouseInDropdown: false })}>
                        <li>New</li>
                        <li>Old</li>
                    </DropdownMenu>
...
</div>
```

**DropdownMenu.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import onClickOutside from 'react-onclickoutside'

class DropdownMenu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            menuOpen: this.props.isOpen,
            highlight: false,
            count: this.props.count | 0,
            selection: null
        }
        this.showDropdown = this.showDropdown.bind(this);
        this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);

        this.menuIsOpen = false;

    }

    handleClickOutside = () => {
        console.log('in menu:'+this.props.inMenu)
        if(!this.props.inMenu) {
            console.log('onClickOutside() method called')
        }
    }

    showDropdown() {
        if(this.props.children) {
            this.setState({
                menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen
            });
        }
    }

    selectItem(e) {
        console.log(e.target.textContent);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.inMenu)
        return <div className="dropdown__menu" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
            {this.props.text} {this.state.count > 0 ? <b>{this.state.count}</b> : ''}
            <div className="dropdown__content" style={this.props.isOpen ? {'display': 'block'} : {'display': 'none'}} onMouseEnter={this.props.onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.props.onMouseLeave}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

export default onClickOutside(DropdownMenu)
```

I am having trouble getting `this.props.isOpen` to become `this.state.isOpen` so that I can use it in `handleClickOutside`.
Another issue is it seems things are being called multiple times, my console is showing this:
[image: Console]

How can I fix these issues?

For reference here is the "click outside" I am using: [Click Outside](https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside)

Comment: `this.props.count | 0` should be `this.props.count || 0`

Comment: This is confusing. `isOpen` doesn't exist in your state, at least not the way you put it in your question, but `menuOpen` does.  Also, you're not using `menuOpen` in `handleClickOutside`; you're using `inMenu`.  Is the real problem that *both* aren't working the way you expect them to?

Comment: Running just the code you have posted, without my edits below, I get the initial `false` in the logs, then `true` and `false` only when the menu is open and when I mouse in and out.  When I click outside, I get the `in menu: false` and `onClickOutside() method called`.  I do not see the undefined entries, which leads me to believe some other code in your app is generating that.  I'm going to continue testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your render function is looking at `this.props`, not `this.state`.

In my mind, this should work (and I streamlined the code a little):

```
<div className="dropdown__content" 
     style={{'display': this.state.menuOpen ? 'block' : 'none'}} 
     onMouseEnter={this.props.onMouseEnter} 
     onMouseLeave={this.props.onMouseLeave} >

    {this.props.children}
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried this but it always comes back as undefined. The isOpen prop comes from the parent but I need to pass it into state so I can use it in the logic of handleClickOutside.

Comment: props is scoped and available inside of the constructor. Try using "props.isOpen" instead of "this.props.isOpen".

Comment: It hasn't made a difference, I keep getting what's in the console image I posted, it seems to be rendering multiple times but I can't see why.

Comment: If the mouse in/out code is telling the parent's state to change, and the state is passed in as a prop (inMenu), then I would wager render() is logging the changing prop 'inMenu', which is what you're seeing in the log.  I've got another comment but I'll add it above.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is you're not tracking the prop changes, i.e. when the props change they're not updating the state. You can do that with:

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
   this.setState({ menuOpen: this.props.isOpen })
}
```

But, in testing, I found a few other things that stood out to me that make this more difficult than it needs to be.  So here's a new answer with working code (one which removes the need for tracking the props).

I can't see (based on what you've posted) why the List component needs to track the menu state and mouse position, so I moved both to the DropdownMenu component itself. You can still pass in the open/closed default as the 'isOpen' prop.

List.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DropdownMenu from './DropdownMenu'

export default class List extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
                <DropdownMenu text="Only show" isOpen={false} >
                            <li>New</li>
                            <li>Old</li>
                </DropdownMenu>
                </div>
    }
}
```

I changed `showDropdown` to `toggleDropdown` because that's a more accurate description of what it's doing. Mouse position was moved to the parent div, and I hooked up `selectItem` to the div containing the children.

DropdownMenu.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import onClickOutside from 'react-onclickoutside'

class DropdownMenu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            menuOpen: props.isOpen,
            highlight: false,
            count: props.count || 0,
            selection: null,
            mouseInDropdown: false,
        }
        this.toggleDropdown = this.toggleDropdown.bind(this);
        this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
    }

    handleClickOutside = () => {
        if(!this.state.mouseInDropdown) {
            // close it no matter what its state is
            this.setState({menuOpen: false}) 
        }
    }

    toggleDropdown() {     
        if(this.props.children) {
            this.setState({
                menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen
            });
        }
    }

    selectItem(e) {
        console.log(e.target.textContent);
    }

    render() {        
        //console.log("Render inMenu: " + this.state.mouseInDropdown)
        return <div className="dropdown__menu"
                    onClick={this.toggleDropdown}                     
                    onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ mouseInDropdown: true })} 
                    onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ mouseInDropdown: false })}> 

            {this.props.text} {this.state.count > 0 ? <b>{this.state.count}</b> : ''}

            <div className="dropdown__content" 
                style={{'display': this.state.menuOpen ? 'block' : 'none'}}
                onClick={this.selectItem} 
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

export default onClickOutside(DropdownMenu)
```